# python float is not digit?

Tags: python, function

This code returns **False**, but when I delete point from float it becomes **True** and I'm trying to understand why. Explain please

```
def isDigit(string):
    string = string.strip()

    if string[:1] == "-":
        cuted = string[1:]
        if cuted.isdigit():
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif string.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

print isDigit("-234.4")
```

also I know my code is not the best and I wonder how can I make it better

Comment: No it's not, because it has the decimal point.

Comment: but task says that it is

Comment: But python says that it's not

Comment: Indent your code properly for one thing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `string[:1]` will be a string if `string` is a string.

Comment: @APorter1031 it is already a string, no need to join

Comment: It's better to return directly from your logic conditionals than to put an extra `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: The answer is already given, but notice that isdigit is a string function. It reads your input as text.

Comment: @jwodder. Whoops. didn't read carefully :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdigit` only checks if all the characters are digits (e.g. `0`, `1`, ... `9`).

Therefore the string `234.4` will return `False` because it also contains a decimal point `.`, that is not a digit.

`help("".isdigit)`

will tell you that to be `True` all characters must be digits and there must be at least one character.

You could use a regular expression to do this kind of checking, for example with something like:

```
import re

def isnumber(x):
    return re.match("-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$", x) is not None
```

that will accept an optional minus sign, followed by a sequence of one or more digits optionally followed by a decimal dot and more digits.

Note that floating point numbers can be accepted by a much wider syntax, including scale exponent and missing parts before and after the decimal point so don't be this strict if you're validating output from a computer. Depending on the context it may be however meaningful to refuse things like `1e4` as numbers from a human.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through your code.

```
if string[:1] == "-":
```

`string[:1]` means "make a string with characters from the start of `string` up to (but not including) index 1." If your string is "foobar", `string[:1]` will be "f". In your example, `string[:1]` will be "-"

```
cuted = string[1:]
```

This will do the opposite, producing a string that contains everything but the first character. In this case, `cuted` would be "234.4"

```
if cuted.isdigit():
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This will test if `cuted` is made up only of numbers. In our case, this is false, because it contains a decimal point. False is returned.

```
elif string.isdigit():
    return True
else:
    return False
```

If the first character was not "-", this is run instead. If you supplied "234.4", this case would be reached, and the test would fail (because "234.4" contains a decimal point), so False would be returned.

Your code appears to be valid *if* what you wanted was:

```
123.3 -> False  
-123.3 -> False  
123 -> True  
-123 -> True
```

On the other hand, if you want your function to say all four of those are numbers, then you need to modify your code. The one way (probably not the best!) to do that would be to have a test case that does something like this:

1. If I split this string on ".", do I get two strings?
2. If so, are both pieces of the string digits?
3. If so, the string is a number.

It's not clear exactly what behavior you want.